# Javascript coding a calculation

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm coding a price calculator in JS and I'm stuck with one formula:

```
number = (parseFloat(newnumber, 10) * parseFloat(1.536, 10)).toString(10);
```

I want to add 7.44 to the value of `newnumber`, before it is multiplied with 1.536 
I've tried several things, but with no success.

Comment: Uses parseFloat... gives it a number literal...

Comment: parseFloat doesn't take a radix like parseInt does.

Comment: Have some "magic". `number = (+newnumber + 7.44) * 1.536;` Now go back to elementary school...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to submit this as an answer, even though someone has put this up a comment while I was typing my answer.

```
number = ((+newnumber + 7.44) * 1.536).toString();
```

That should give you a string representation of the summed value.

Comment: `NaN` when `newnumber` is not a proper floating number
eg : newnumber = '2.54sajsd';

Comment: I would also reply NaN if someone asked me to add '2.54sajsd' to '7.44' Input validation needs to take place at some point in the app, dont you think?

Comment: Depends .  Use case - adding temperatures (var temperature = '24.6 F';) same temperature can be used in floating point calculations as well as to display with unit as a string.

Comment: Thats a pretty bad use case. Your numerical values should be numbers, not formatted strings. Formatting happens during output or display. Its pretty rudimentary and error prone to have to convert between string and number - especially for temperature, which can be converted, added, subtracted and then displayed as Celsius or Fahrenheit. My advice, store it as a numerical value, do all your calculations/method-calls on the number and then format it just before you display it.

Comment: I don't think so. Lets say my service returns data in a variable as '24.6F' as the temperature. 
Now I've to always display it in Celsius. Why wouldn't I just do - `$("#randomOutputDiv").html((parsefloat(temperature)-32)*5/9);` rather than `var temperatureNumeric = parseFloat(temperature);$("#randomOutputDiv").html(temperatureNumeric-32)*5/9);`? Assuming I don't have any other operations on temperature.

Comment: Another example would be extracting base from scientific notations - +23.653e2

Comment: Wut? Why would you do `$("#randomOutputDiv").html((parsefloat(temperature)-32)*5/9);` instead of `$("#randomOutputDiv").html(getCelciusString());` or `(getFahrenheit()-32)*5/9`- encapsulate your calculations and encapsulate your formatting code. Then you can reuse that code all over the place. This means that if you display '45C' in lots of places, you can later change this to '45Celcius' or '45 Degrees Celcius' easily, you just change one function, instead of all of your .html() functions. Separate your display code from your logic.

Comment: @Vandesh Why are you making your life difficult? Why would temperature store 45F or 45C. If I did getAge(), instinctivly I would expect a number i.e. 32 not "32 and a half", getAge(), getShoeSize(), getFahrenheit(), getHeight(), getWidth() - these should all return numerical data, the comments and API's will tell us what the units of measurements are. You then format and display the data the way you need to. Your program should not have to deal with complex logic and also deal with formatting every time it needs to add or multiply or divide a number, otherwise your program has poor design.

Comment: At the expense of sounding argumentative (Any, further if I have to say would take it on chat), I would go ahead and say that yes, in reality we SHOULD do something like you said good design, re-usable code and what not. In all this jargon, my basic counter of what you CAN do using `parsefloat` instead of just producing an NAN error in some cases, has been side-lined. I still believe parsefloat should be used, if it CAN! And that's my basic point, of using parsefloat instead of +

Comment: I deal in UI - A live example : Once a client asked to let the textbox which should take in amount to also include currency say $. So, without validations in place, a user could input 12.34$ or simply 12.34. Now given I need to add up, do some calculations on these values,(according to me) I SHOULD use `parsefloat`. Yes, I would wrap it in a function. Yes, I would store it in a separate variable, however, I'd still use `parsefloat` instead of plain adding it.

Comment: I would like to end this discussion, as it feels like I am beginning to repeat myself, so I close with the following: in your example you have user input, this NEEDS to be validated (as I have said in my first comment) and parsed - but otherwise, if your program is designed nicely, why parseFloat where you know there is a float value. If my program stores `var taxRate = 0.2;`, I would not parseFloat it, unless the user could meddle with the variable somehow. The original poster did not specify that he needed user input to be read from the UI - so why presume?

Answer (score 2):

Use parentheses to make the addition before the multiplication.

```
number = ((parseFloat(newnumber) + 7.44) * 1.536).toString();
```

Notes: `parseFloat` doesn't have a radix parameter. There is no reason to parse the number `1.536`, that will only turn it to a string and then back to the same number again. The default for the radix parameter for `toString` is 10, so that isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

`number = ((parseFloat(newnumber) + 7.44) * parseFloat(1.536)).toString();`?

Just use parentheses to separate out the operations.  Simple fix.

Comment: For not removing the radix

Answer (score 0):

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MxL6c/1/)

Try the following code -

```
var newnumber = '1';
var number = ((parseFloat(newnumber) + 7.44) * parseFloat(1.536)).toString(10);
alert(number);
```